When I select the checkbox, it displays its value just fine. When I de-select it, it continues to display

In the image, I first selected the first two checkboxes and clicked to calculate. Then, I unchecked the second one and clicked again to calculate, and it gave me still both values and total price. Also, when I click on the clear button and check it again, it does the same thing but with the price "0".


const calcButton = document.getElementById('calc-button');
const clearButton = document.getElementById('clear-button');
const result = document.getElementById('result');

let currentValue = 0;
let totalPrice = 0;
let exams = [];

function getCheckboxValue(event) {
  const checkboxValue = event.target.value;
  if (event.target.checked) {
    currentValue = checkboxValue;
    getPrice(currentValue);
    getName(currentValue);
  } else {
    currentValue = '';
  }
}

function getPrice() {
  let price = document.querySelector(`#price${currentValue}`);
  let priceText = price.textContent.replace(',', '.');
  return totalPrice += parseInt(priceText, 10);
}

function getName() {
  let name = document.querySelector(`#name${currentValue}`);
  nameText = name.textContent.trim();
  exams.push(nameText);
  return exams;
}

function displayTotal() {
  let examsList = exams.join("<br>")
  result.style.display = "block";
  result.innerHTML =
    `<span>Deu <strong>${totalPrice}</strong> conto</span>
    <br><br>
   <span>Exames marcados:
    <br>
   ${examsList}</span>
  `;
  return result;
}

function clear() {
  result.innerHTML = ''
  result.style.display = "none";
  currentValue = 0;
  totalPrice = 0;
}


const checkboxes = document.querySelectorAll('input[type="checkbox"]');
checkboxes.forEach(checkbox => {
  checkbox.addEventListener('click', getCheckboxValue);
});

calcButton.addEventListener("click", displayTotal);
clearButton.addEventListener("click", clear);
<style>
  @import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Michroma&display=swap');
</style>
<h1>Calculadora da Duda</h1>

<table border="1">
  <tr>
    <th>Check</th>
    <th>Código</th>
    <th>Nome</th>
    <th>Preço</th>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <label for="checkbox1"></label>
    <td><input type="checkbox" name="check" title="check" value="1"></td>
    <td id="code1">17HPC</td>
    <td id="name1">17 HIDROXIPROGESTERONA</td>
    <td id="price1">30,00</td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <label for="checkbox2"></label>
    <td><input type="checkbox" name="check" title="check" value="2"></td>
    <td id="code2">17OHC</td>
    <td id="name2">17 HIDROXICORTICOIDES</td>
    <td id="price2">55,00</td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <label for="checkbox3"></label>
    <td><input type="checkbox" name="check" title="check" value="3"></td>
    <td id="code3">17OHP</td>
    <td id="name3">17 ALFA-HIDROXIPROGESTERONA</td>
    <td id="price3">30,00</td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <label for="checkbox4"></label>
    <td><input type="checkbox" name="check" title="check" value="4"></td>
    <td id="code4">5HIAC</td>
    <td id="name4">ACIDO 5 HIDROXI INDOL ACETICO</td>
    <td id="price4">90,00</td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <label for="checkbox5"></label>
    <td><input type="checkbox" name="check" title="check" value="5"></td>
    <td id="code5">5NUC</td>
    <td id="name5">5 NUCLEOTIDASE</td>
    <td id="price5">130,00</td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <label for="checkbox6"></label>
    <td><input type="checkbox" name="check" title="check" value="6"></td>
    <td id="code6">A1A</td>
    <td id="name6">ALFA 1 ANTI-TRIPSINA</td>
    <td id="price6">30,00</td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <label for="checkbox7"></label>
    <td><input type="checkbox" name="check" title="check" value="7"></td>
    <td id="code7">A1AF</td>
    <td id="name7">ALFA 1 ANTI-TRIPSINA FECAL</td>
    <td id="price7">80,00</td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <label for="checkbox8"></label>
    <td><input type="checkbox" name="check" title="check" value="8"></td>
    <td id="code8">AACH1</td>
    <td id="name8">TESTE RAPIDO CHIKUNGUNYA IGG/IGM</td>
    <td id="price8">125,00</td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <label for="checkbox9"></label>
    <td><input type="checkbox" name="check" title="check" value="9"></td>
    <td id="code9">AACHI</td>
    <td id="name9">ANTICORPOS ANTI CHIKUNGUNYA IGG/IGM</td>
    <td id="price9">240,00</td>
  </tr>

</table>

<div id="final-buttons">
  <button type="button" id="calc-button">Calcular</button>
  <button type="button" id="clear-button">Limpar</button>
</div>

<div id="result"></div>




Please include the relevant html.

You only reset totalPrice, et. al. when you click "Clear". Seems like you might need to recalculate on every checkbox click, even if it's unchecked.

The main issue with your code is due to the fact that you are not handling the deselection of checkboxes to remove values, only adding new ones when they are checked.
You can fix the problem, simplify your code and improve its quality by changing the pattern to only calculate the totals and update the DOM when you click the 'Calcular' button, instead of attempting to keep a running total when the checkboxes are interacted with. To do this you can retrieve the checked checkboxes from the DOM and loop through them, as the example below shows.
Also note that there's a couple of additional tweaks you can make:

Remove the label elements. They are not being rendered at all as you've put them outside of the table structure, so they are redundant and can be removed.
Don't use incremental id attributes. It just complicates your code and makes it harder to maintain and easier to break. Instead use common class attributes and relate content together using DOM traversal methods.



const checkboxes = [...document.querySelectorAll('input[type="checkbox"]')];
const calcButton = document.querySelector('#calc-button');
const clearButton = document.querySelector('#clear-button');
const result = document.querySelector('#result');

function displayTotal() {
  let totalPrice = 0;
  let examsList = [];
  
  checkboxes.filter(cb => cb.checked).forEach(cb => {    
    const row = cb.closest('tr');
    totalPrice += parseInt(row.querySelector('.price').textContent.replace(',', '.'), 10);
    examsList.push(row.querySelector('.name').textContent);
  });

  result.style.display = "block";
  result.innerHTML = `<span>Deu <strong>${totalPrice}</strong> conto</span><br><br><span>Exames marcados:<br>${examsList.join('<br />')}</span>`;
  return result;
}

function clear() {
  result.innerHTML = ''
  result.style.display = "none";
  currentValue = 0;
  totalPrice = 0;
}

calcButton.addEventListener("click", displayTotal);
clearButton.addEventListener("click", clear);
<style>
  @import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Michroma&display=swap');
</style>
<h1>Calculadora da Duda</h1>

<table border="1">
  <tr>
    <th>Check</th>
    <th>Código</th>
    <th>Nome</th>
    <th>Preço</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><input type="checkbox" name="check" title="check" value="1"></td>
    <td class="code">17HPC</td>
    <td class="name">17 HIDROXIPROGESTERONA</td>
    <td class="price">30,00</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><input type="checkbox" name="check" title="check" value="2"></td>
    <td class="code">17OHC</td>
    <td class="name">17 HIDROXICORTICOIDES</td>
    <td class="price">55,00</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><input type="checkbox" name="check" title="check" value="3"></td>
    <td class="code">17OHP</td>
    <td class="name">17 ALFA-HIDROXIPROGESTERONA</td>
    <td class="price">30,00</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><input type="checkbox" name="check" title="check" value="4"></td>
    <td class="code">5HIAC</td>
    <td class="name">ACIDO 5 HIDROXI INDOL ACETICO</td>
    <td class="price">90,00</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><input type="checkbox" name="check" title="check" value="5"></td>
    <td class="code">5NUC</td>
    <td class="name">5 NUCLEOTIDASE</td>
    <td class="price">130,00</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><input type="checkbox" name="check" title="check" value="6"></td>
    <td class="code">A1A</td>
    <td class="name">ALFA 1 ANTI-TRIPSINA</td>
    <td class="price">30,00</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><input type="checkbox" name="check" title="check" value="7"></td>
    <td class="code">A1AF</td>
    <td class="name">ALFA 1 ANTI-TRIPSINA FECAL</td>
    <td class="price">80,00</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><input type="checkbox" name="check" title="check" value="8"></td>
    <td class="code">AACH1</td>
    <td class="name">TESTE RAPIDO CHIKUNGUNYA IGG/IGM</td>
    <td class="price">125,00</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><input type="checkbox" name="check" title="check" value="9"></td>
    <td class="code">AACHI</td>
    <td class="name">ANTICORPOS ANTI CHIKUNGUNYA IGG/IGM</td>
    <td class="price">240,00</td>
  </tr>
</table>

<div id="final-buttons">
  <button type="button" id="calc-button">Calcular</button>
  <button type="button" id="clear-button">Limpar</button>
</div>

<div id="result"></div>




Thank you so much! I'll definitely try this. Also thank you for the observation about the labels and ID's, I was confused about them too but was ignoring that. As a beginner there is a lot of elements I haven't studied.

Prefer to work this way, with only one function to do clearance and compute your sum (computeSum()) in this code:


const
  calcButton  = document.getElementById('calc-button')
, clearButton = document.getElementById('clear-button')
, result      = document.getElementById('result')
, myTableBody = document.querySelector('#my-table tbody')
, ES_Nums     = new Intl.NumberFormat('es-ES', { minimumFractionDigits: 2 })
, rowsTable =
  [ { cod: '17HPC', Nome: '17 HIDROXIPROGESTERONA',              Preço:  30.00 }
  , { cod: '17OHC', Nome: '17 HIDROXICORTICOIDES',               Preço:  55.00 }
  , { cod: '17OHP', Nome: '17 ALFA-HIDROXIPROGESTERONA',         Preço:  30.00 }
  , { cod: '5HIAC', Nome: 'ACIDO 5 HIDROXI INDOL ACETICO',       Preço:  90.00 }
  , { cod: '5NUC',  Nome: '5 NUCLEOTIDASE',                      Preço: 130.00 }
  , { cod: 'A1A',   Nome: 'ALFA 1 ANTI-TRIPSINA',                Preço:  30.00 }
  , { cod: 'A1AF',  Nome: 'ALFA 1 ANTI-TRIPSINA FECAL',          Preço:  80.00 }
  , { cod: 'AACH1', Nome: 'TESTE RAPIDO CHIKUNGUNYA IGG/IGM',    Preço: 125.00 }
  , { cod: 'AACHI', Nome: 'ANTICORPOS ANTI CHIKUNGUNYA IGG/IGM', Preço: 240.00 }
  ];
rowsTable.forEach( (row,indx) =>
  {
  let tr = myTableBody.insertRow();
  tr.insertCell().innerHTML   = `<input type="checkbox" title="check mi" value="${indx}">`;
  tr.insertCell().textContent = row.cod;
  tr.insertCell().textContent = row.Nome;
  tr.insertCell().textContent = ES_Nums.format( row.Preço);
  });
myTableBody.addEventListener('click', e =>
  {
  let chkBx = e.target.closest('tr').querySelector('input[type="checkbox"]')
  chkBx.checked = !chkBx.checked;
  })
calcButton.addEventListener('click', computeSum )
  ;
clearButton.addEventListener('click', e =>
  {
  myTableBody.querySelectorAll('input[type="checkbox"]:checked').forEach( chkBx => chkBx.checked = false );
  computeSum();
  })
function computeSum()
  {
  result.textContent = '';  // clear content
  let
    total = 0
  , xRow  = [];
    ;
  myTableBody.querySelectorAll('input[type="checkbox"]:checked').forEach( chkBx => 
    {
    total += rowsTable[ chkBx.value ].Preço;
    xRow.push(+chkBx.value);
    });
    if (xRow.length === 0) return
    ;
  result.innerHTML = `
    <span>Deu <strong>${ES_Nums.format(total)}</strong> conto</span>
    <br><br>
    <span>Exames marcados:
      <br>
      ${ xRow.map( n => rowsTable[n].Nome).join('<br>')}
    </span>`;
  }
body {
  font-family     : Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-size       : 14px;
  }
table {
  background      : darkblue;
  border-collapse : separate;
  border-spacing  : 1px;
  margin-bottom   : .8em;
  }
table caption {
  font-size   : 1.4rem;
  font-weight : bold;
  padding     : .4em 0;
  }
th {
  background-color : #7fccff;
  padding          : .4em .6em ;
  }
tr {
  --bgTdColor : whitesmoke;
  }
td {
  background-color : var(--bgTdColor);
  padding          : .4em;
  text-align       : center;
  }
td:last-of-type {
  text-align       : right;
  }
tr:hover {
  cursor      : pointer;
  --bgTdColor : orange;
  }
td input[type="checkbox"] { /* let it be only clicked on row action */
  pointer-events: none;
  }
<table id="my-table">
  <caption>Calculadora da Duda</caption>
  <thead>
    <tr><th>Check</th><th>Código</th><th>Nome</th><th>Preço</th></tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
  </tbody>
</table>

<div id="final-buttons">
  <button type="button" id="calc-button">Calcular</button>
  <button type="button" id="clear-button">Limpar</button>
</div>

<div id="result"></div>




Thank you! But I don't know if that array of the table would work because I will be adding 500 or more TDs to that, for note I'm converting a 12 page PDF list. But that's a really clever way of doing it
